# Solve wordpress 404 errors on empty tag and category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

All my tags and categories have content in themselves. They do have additional content if any posts have been associated to the given category/tag, but they also contain useful information on their own.

However, WordPress throws 404 errors for these. I rather not patch WordPress itself due to maintenance so that leaves... no good solutions? (Writing a plugin? None seem to be available, so that indiciates that's a nogo as well)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this particularly in the past, but I have written plugins that alter the template based on query variables via the [template_include](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) hook.

How categories translate their permalinks to [query_vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars) is as follows:

```
example.net/?cat=catname
OR
example.net/?category_name=catname
```

So if you write a function attached to the template_includes hook that does something like the following:

```
function captureEmptyCat($template)
{

    if( get_query_var('category_name','false') ||  get_query_var('cat','false') )
    {
        //Do WP_QUERY to count posts in category, assign count to $categoryCount

        if($categoryCount <= 0)
        {
            $template = "path/to/custom/template.php"
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Then in your custom template (can be in your theme or plugin or really anywhere you can reach via file path) do a proper WP_QUERY for the information you want.

This code can be in the theme's function.php file or in a stand alone plugin, that is up to you to decide based on your needs.